# In PCManFM, is it possible to launch and connect to a SFTP server?

Tags: sftp, pcmanfm

For example, I know that I can use the command `pcmanfm` to launch PCManFM and I can also type `pcmanfm ~/Desktop` to open PCManFM to the desktop folder. However, `pcmanfm sftp://[ipaddresshere]` gives the error

```
[xcb] Unknown request in queue while dequeuing
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
pcmanfm: ../../src/xcb_io.c:179: dequeue_pending_request: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_unknown_req_in_deq' failed.
Aborted
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong. So, how can I open PCManFM and connect to a server with one command? I want to place this command in a .desktop file for easy access.

Thunar and Nautilus both allow me to do this easily by launching them with the same argument but if possible I would like to be able to do this with PCManFM since I use it elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question almost contains the answer...
for me this command line works:

```
pcmanfm 'sftp://aries:2222'
```

In my case the "SFTP Server" is an Android device running [SshHelper](https://arachnoid.com/android/SSHelper/) App;
In the App the port is defined as `2222` instead of default `22`
My Ubuntu knows hostname via my router - the device `aries` is ping-able.

**EDIT:**
On my new device (Sony XZ2 compact, running on Pie) the latest SshHelper was not working any longer - so Termux with ssh-Package `apt install openssh` helps. In Termux' `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` my Ubuntu's PublicKey is added.
Default port for Termux' sshd is `8022` (Termux widget to start a script for `sshd &` is a handy thing).

Example of pcmanfm "storage" is Termux' `~/storage/` and `3933-3933` is my SdCard:

```
pcmanfm 'sftp://xz2c:8022/storage/3933-3933/media/audio'
```